# Magento Newsletter Subscription Confirmation Succesful not sent

Tags: email, newsletter, transactional-mail

We set the option that a user needs to confirm their subscription to yes.
In `System  >  Configuration > Newsletter > Need to confirm **(YES)**`

That works good, but when a user did confirm his/her email address, they do not receive the Success Email.

How can we send the Succes Email after they confirmed their email address?

Comment: Add a plugin and this code will work @Klettseb
its good to create a module instead of over writing on the core file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134820)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134820)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`

copy the whole content to

```
MyVendor/Tweaks/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php
```

Then find the below

```
public function confirm($code)
    {
        if($this->getCode()==$code) {
            $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
                ->setIsStatusChanged(true)
                ->save();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And replace it with:

```
public function confirm($code)
    {
        if($this->getCode()==$code) {
            $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
                ->setIsStatusChanged(true)
                ->save();

                $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Commenting for posterity... it is better practice to put this sort of update in a module. Editing app/code/core directly 1) may have unintended consequences, and 2) can complicate the installation of security patches. Instead, you could make MyVendor/Tweaks/ and extend the Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php to create MyVendor/Tweaks/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php. Check out [this similar thread](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133186/how-do-i-override-rewrite-a-block-class-in-magento-1).

Comment: how it do for magento 2????

Comment: This solution is not working for me... :-(  I override the  Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber and try this solution but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

Klettseb's solution should work, but I'd recommend a lighter approach instead of overriding the entire Subscriber class:

`\app\etc\modules\Yourcompany_Newsletter.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
      <modules>
          <Yourcompany_Newsletter>
              <active>true</active>
              <codePool>local</codePool>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
          </Yourcompany_Newsletter>
      </modules>
  </config>
```

`\app\code\local\Yourcompany\Newsletter\etc\config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
      <modules>
          <Yourcompany_Newsletter>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
          </Yourcompany_Newsletter>
      </modules>
      <global>
          <models>
              <yourcompany_newsletter>
                  <class>Yourcompany_Newsletter_Model</class>
              </yourcompany_newsletter>
              <newsletter>
                  <rewrite>
                     <subscriber>Yourcompany_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber</subscriber>
                  </rewrite>
              </newsletter>
          </models>
      </global>
  </config>
```

`\app\code\local\Yourcompany\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber.php`

```
  <?php

  class Yourcompany_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
  {

      /**
       * send the confirmation-success email if newsletter subscription is confirmed
       */
      public function confirm($code)
      {
          $isConfirmed = parent::confirm($code);

          if ($isConfirmed == true) {
              $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
          }

          return $isConfirmed;
      }

  }
```