# Added function to class core not returning anything

Tags: magento-1.9, class

I want add a function to the core class. To do this I have added a file to extend the class core but when I call the function it's returning nothing.

Comment: Please post the code you used to rewrite the class

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to rewrite that class in your custom module config.xml and then your class will load first and for core functions it will take core classes

**Here is below sample code you can rewrite block classes,
The same way you can `rewrite` helpers and `Model` classes**

If I want to rewrite this block class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create then I code in my module config.xml Like Below.

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
               <sales_order_create>Trimantra_Smallchanges_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create</sales_order_create>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

And In my class `Trimantra_Smallchanges_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create`

I code Like Below

```
class Trimantra_Smallchanges_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create {
       //My Function Or funcions That I want to Rewrite..
}
```

**In blow url I have written a blog you can also check that for more reference**

http://blog.trimantra.com/magento-difference-override-rewrite/

**Or you can check blow answer for more detail**

[How do I override/rewrite a block class in Magento 1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133186/how-do-i-override-rewrite-a-block-class-in-magento-1)