# rewriting core block issue

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, magento-1, overrides

I have trouble figuring out whats wrong with my rewrite. I have used the answer of [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133186/how-do-i-override-rewrite-a-block-class-in-magento-1) as a reference.

I'm trying to rewrite the core block:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Create\Header.php
```

Here's my module's config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyNameSpace_MyModule>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyNameSpace_MyModule>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <Adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <Sales_Order_Create_Header>MyNameSpace_MyModule_Block_Header</Sales_Order_Create_Header> 
            </rewrite>
        </Adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

This is the path to my block where i want to rewrite the function in Header.php:

```
app\code\local\MyNameSpace\MyModule\Block\Header.php
```

Content of Header.php:

```
<?php

class MyNameSpace_MyModule_Block_Header extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Header {
    //My rewrite
}
```

Comment: try lowercase in your `config.xml`  in tags `<Adminhtml>` and `<Sales_Order_Create_Header>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_create_header>MyNameSpace_MyModule_Block_Header</sales_order_create_header> 
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```