# Magento SUPEE 9697 1.9.2.2 fails at Image.php

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, ce-1.9.2.2, supee-9767

I'm attempting to apply patch 9697 (via patch `PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56`) to Magento CE 1.9.2.2 however it's failing.  The log states:

```
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
can't find file to patch at input line 351
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|
|index 14c4d98..176c17b 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
```

However when I have a look in **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator** there is no **Image.php** file.  I've also downloaded a fresh 1.9.2.2 and there is no `Image.php` file there either.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because **you are missing the SUPEE-7405 patch**. This patch adds the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php` file.

I strongly suggest you run your website against magereport.com to check which patch you're missing and install the missing patches before this one.

Comment: Magereport shows clear for 7405.

Comment: @ChristopheMacAlister the magereport check does not check for every file it checks some frontend changes. Check the `app/etc/applied.patches` file

Comment: This was my issue, was on Enterprise 1.14.2.2. Thanks Raphael

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty Sure that you are getting error in this file `checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php` because of following  reasons:

**1st Reason:**

May be this file has wrong file permission set 644 default permission to this file and check

**2nd Reason:**

You have manually modified this file: in this case download `magento 1.9.3` and revert this file from that version and apply this patch after that again put your custom code into that.

> I Advice you to not to modify core files instead rewriting the
>   classes

Comment: How to rewrite the classes instead of delete and replaced by downloaded fresh core file.

Comment: @zus https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133186/how-do-i-override-rewrite-a-block-class-in-magento-1

Comment: how can i solve the 9767 v2 patch error https://justpaste.it/1e8te

Answer (score 0):

Magereport.com showed that 7405 was applied correctly and when attempting to apply the 7405 patch I got messages saying that it looks like the patch has been previously applied.

However, I downloaded Image.php from [A Github Repo of prepatched Magento files](https://github.com/magecomp/Magento-Pre-Patched-Files) and ran the patch again.  This time it worked.